# Windows Phone 8: How can I make a map's pushpin textbox to stay on top of any other elements on the map?

Tags: windows-phone-8, z-index, pushpin, here-api

I have a map with 100 pushpins. Every time I tap a pushpin, a textbox with description is opened near that pushpin (only 1 textbox can be opened at a time, when you tap a pushpin, the previous opened textbox is closed first), but sometimes the textbox is not on top of other pushpins, other pushpins appear above the textbox, making it hard to read the description. I've tried using Canvas and Canvas.ZIndex, but nothing worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and I solved it my removing and adding the object again whenever it was tapped.

```
MapLayer theLayer = new MapLayer();
MapOverlay theOverlay = new MapOverlay()
{
    GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lng)
};
var pp = new StackPanel { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical };
var img = new Image()
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute)),
    Width = 50,
    Height = 50
};
pp.Children.Add(img);
img.Tap += (object emitter, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) => {
    theLayer.Remove(theOverlay);
    theLayer.Add(theOverlay);
};
theOverlay.Content = pp;
theLayer.Add(theOverlay);
```

Hope this helps!